# Setting up custom 500 error page on SC 9.1

Tags: error-handling

I'm trying to setup custom 500 page on SC 9.1

I'm following this procedure: https://www.geekhive.com/buzz/post/2017/08/a-complete-guide-to-configuring-friendly-error-pages-in-sitecore-part-2-500-pages/

I get this error:

[image]

Note that it seems like it's working but there is an error "...while executing the custom error page...".

My configuration is like this:
[image]

NOTES:

- In order to test the 500 page, I am turning off the SQL Server
  Windows Service.
- The <customErrors> node is in the <system.web> node
  of the web.config
- I switched from using a .aspx file to a .html file
  to simplify things.. same error though.

Anyone seen this before?

Comment: Can you test by throwing an error on a component instead? I'm not positive if sql outages/failed connection strings are caught properly.

Comment: I have separate 500 error handling at the component level such that the page will still render.

Comment: To test the `500.html` logic though, can you intentionally throw an error?

Comment: Okay. I re-enabled SQL Server and added an explicit exception in a ServicesConfigurator. I get the same error page/message.

Comment: Try removing the runat="server" from the 500.html <head>

Comment: Ah, good eye. Unfortunately, I still get the same error after removing the runat="server" though.

Comment: There must be something else going on. I have a 9.1.0 habitat install and I tried exactly what you did and I'm receiving the proper 500 page. I intentionally broke a reference in a view that is on the homepage. Your best bet is to check out a Failed Request Trace Log: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/troubleshoot/using-failed-request-tracing/using-failed-request-tracing-rules-to-troubleshoot-application-request-routing-arr Be sure to specify a 500 error.

Comment: @jrap Thanks for testing that. That rules out some 9.1 bug then. I've been looking at the Failed Request Trace log already but nothing stands out.

Comment: Except maybe this: GENERAL_NOT_SEND_CUSTOM_ERROR Reason="SETSTATUS_TRYSKIP"

Comment: @jrap So I just installed a clean instance of 9.1 and tried to implement the custom 500 page. I see the same issue. Can you try your Habitat 9.1 site with SQL Server shut off?

Comment: Can you find me on slack?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I worked with @sitecorepm on Slack to run a few tests.

### Why It Fails

If Sitecore has not been previously initialized the custom error page will not appear.

#### Failed Test Using Habitat 9.1.0

1. Stop SQL Server
2. Reset IIS
3. View site

You will receive the generic IIS Runtime Error page, even with `<customErrors>` set to `"On"`.

[image: Habitat 910 Runtime Error]

#### Successful Test Using Habitat 9.1.0

1. Start SQL Server
2. Reset IIS (optional)
3. View site (it should come up successfully, at this point Sitecore has the connection data it needs)
4. Stop SQL Server
5. View site

You will now receive the custom 500 error page.

[image: Habitat 910 Custom Error]

### Further Note About Breaking Connection Strings

I also tested the intentional change of a connection string- by changing the password to an incorrect value, for example. This change still results in the generic Runtime Error being displayed. In other words, it is not accounted for in this answer.

Comment: I have submitted a ticket to Sitecore for a resolution to this issue. Thanks for taking the time to help troubleshoot this!